# How to unzip folder with symlinks

Tags: java, symlink, unzip

**I Have:** zipped folder that contains relative symbolic links (symlinks)

**What i want to achieve:** unzip folder and still have symbolic links

I prefer to use java.util.zip but im not even sure if it is possible.

So, the question is: how to unzip folder, and **do not** replace symlink with copy of a file?

If it is not possible for zip, is it possible for tar?

Comment: Are those symbolic links relative, at least?

Comment: exactly, they are relative "../lib/"

Comment: OK, it seems that the JSR 203 zip filesystem provider in Oracle's Java 8 can't do that (just tried) :/

Comment: One of the reasons for this to be hard to do is that dropping a zip-file with symlinks and having them preserved can lead to [vulnerabilities](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/73718/how-zip-symlink-works)

Comment: so, if it is not possible for zip, is it possible for tar.gz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that apache [commons-compress](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/) has [support for symlinks](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/apidocs/org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/zip/ZipArchiveEntry.html#isUnixSymlink%28%29) - in the sense that it can tell you if an entry is a symlink, and what it points to. You would then re-create the symlinks using [Files.createSymbolicLink](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createSymbolicLink-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-)

So - definitely possible, if a bit of a hassle since uncompressing a zip-file in commons-compress is sort of [convoluted](http://hubpages.com/technology/Zipping-and-Unzipping-Nested-Directories-in-Java-using-Apache-Commons-Compress).